# Deployment exception on Payara

Tags: java, cdi, glassfish-4.1, payara

I have been sitting with a problem deploying an application to Payara 4.1.1.171.

The deployment goes thru up to a point where it fails with an exception.

Stack Trace below:

```
Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:Exception List with 2 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type IterableProvider<ComponentInvocationHandler> with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject private org.glassfish.api.invocation.InvocationManagerImpl(@Optional IterableProvider<ComponentInvocationHandler>)
  at org.glassfish.api.invocation.InvocationManagerImpl.<init>(InvocationManagerImpl.java:91)
```

And lower down in the trace.

```
Exception 1 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Logger with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject org.glassfish.api.admin.AdminCommandLock.logger
  at org.glassfish.api.admin.AdminCommandLock.logger(AdminCommandLock.java:0)
```

Have read allot on CDI and possible solutions to the problem but none currently addresses this issue.

The application is currently deployed on another server where its running, but for some odd reason it will not deploy to this server. Have also upgraded the server as well as downgraded the server, but all having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue. It was caused by a custom threadpool executor service I have packaged before. This packaged contained the glassfish-api library causing a conflict during class loading, removing this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the test project I opened keeping in mind that it's loading something that causes Payara to throw this error. There are actually two Spring Framework dependencies involved. They are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When only the first one, jakarta.servlet-api, is included, Payara deploys the app just fine. However, when the second one, spring-web, is included, that causes Payara to throw the error " CDI is not available.".

This is the simplest web app I could think of. It consists of 1 java file:

```
package com.test;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *h
 * @author Glenn Barnard
 * 
 * @version 3.0, 10-27-2020
 */

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4106307982613351195L;

    
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }  

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        String responseText = "Welcome to the Test Servlet";;

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = null;
        try {
            out = response.getWriter();
            out.println(responseText);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (out != null)
                out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And the POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>bw</groupId>
    <artifactId>testwebproject</artifactId>
    <version>Test</version>
    <name>TestWeb</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- or whatever version you use -->
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
 
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Given that the web MVC Springframework uses injection, it makes sense that it needs CDI.